# Different result of same numpy mean calculation on two computers

Tags: numpy, python-2.7

I have two computers with python 2.7.2 (MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32) and numpy 1.6.1.
But

```
numpy.mean(data)
```

returns

```
1.13595094681 on my old computer
```

and

```
1.13595104218 on my new computer
```

where

```
Data = [ 0.20227873 -0.02738848  0.59413314  0.88547146  1.26513398  1.21090782
1.62445402  1.80423951  1.58545554  1.26801944  1.22551131  1.16882968
1.19972098  1.41940248  1.75620842  1.28139281  0.91190684  0.83705413
1.19861531  1.30767155]
```

In both cases

```
s=0
for n in data[:20]:
  s+=n
print s/20
```

gives

```
1.1359509334
```

Can anyone explain why and how to avoid?

Mads

Comment: How many values do you sum up? How large are the values? (max(x)/min(x)/max(abs(x))/min(abs(x))

Comment: I don't know anything about numpy, but I doubt someone familiar with numpy could tell you why without further details.  Please give the value of data and preferably more differences between the two computers.

Comment: I have change the question a little

Comment: Can you check the datatype of `data` (I mean the dtype, float32, etc)?

Comment: The mean calculation doesn't do anything special really AFAIK (just sum up, divide by length). But I would still guess its simple difference in hardware floating point precision and yeah its probably float32 to begin with, so the difference is not actually large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to avoid any differences between the two, then make them explicitly 32-bit or 64-bit float arrays. NumPy uses several other libraries that may be 32 or 64 bit.  Note that rounding can occur in your print statements as well:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [0.20227873, -0.02738848,  0.59413314,  0.88547146,  1.26513398,
         1.21090782, 1.62445402,  1.80423951,  1.58545554,  1.26801944,
         1.22551131,  1.16882968, 1.19972098,  1.41940248,  1.75620842,
         1.28139281,  0.91190684,  0.83705413, 1.19861531,  1.30767155]
>>> x32 = np.array(a, np.float32)
>>> x64 = np.array(a, np.float64)
>>> x32.mean()
1.135951042175293
>>> x64.mean()
1.1359509335
>>> print x32.mean()
1.13595104218
>>> print x64.mean()
1.1359509335
```

Another point to note is that if you have lower level libraries (e.g., atlas, lapack) that are multi-threaded, then for large arrays, you may have differences in your result regardless, due to possible variable order of operations and floating point precision.

Also, you are at the limit of precision for 32 bit numbers:

```
>>> x32.sum()
22.719021
>>> np.array(sorted(x32)).sum()
22.719019
```

Comment: Converting the array to float 64 on my new computer seems to help

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have `Float32` arrays (single precision). With single precision, the operations are only accurate to 6 decimal place. Hence your results are the same up to the 6th decimal place (after the decimal point, rounding the last digit), but they are not accurate after that. Different architectures/machines/compilers will yield the different results after that. If you want the same results you should use higher precision arrays (e.g. `Float64`).